# What does this error means Cannot find source for binding with reference

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to bind Control Property
This is my second day trying and can't make it work. I am getting an error

> "Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=_this'.
> BindingExpression:Path=PlaceHolder; DataItem=null; target element is
> 'TextBlock' (Name='title'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String').
> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=_this'.
> BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is
> 'TextBox' (Name='email'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')"

I have follow the tutorial but cant find the error. thank you for your help.

frontend page

```
<CustomControls:TextBoxAnimatedPlaceholder 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        PlaceHolder="Email" />
    <CustomControls:TextBoxAnimatedPlaceholder 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        PlaceHolder="Password" 
        />
```

Custom control

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.CustomControls.TextBoxAnimatedPlaceholder"  
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.CustomControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MinWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="credentialTxTtitleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding PlaceHolder, ElementName=_this}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#a3a3a4" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>

       
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0" />
        <Style.Triggers >
            <DataTrigger Binding= "{Binding Text, ElementName=email}" Value="">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard SpeedRatio="10">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="20"/>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard SpeedRatio="10">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="15"/>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0 0 0 30" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="credentialTxTStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay ,  ElementName=_this}"/>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Style.Triggers >
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=title}" Value="15">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard SpeedRatio="10">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="20"/>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0 20 0 0 " />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard SpeedRatio="10">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="15"/>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border
    CornerRadius="10"
    Background="White"
    Height="70">

    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="23" ShadowDepth="5" Direction="270" Color="WhiteSmoke"></DropShadowEffect>
    </Border.Effect>

    <Grid Margin="20,6">
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="title"
            Style="{StaticResource credentialTxTtitleStyle}" />
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="email"
            Style="{StaticResource credentialTxTStyle}" />
    </Grid>

</Border>
```

code behind

```
 public string PlaceHolder
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceHolderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceHolderProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceHolder.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceHolder", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxAnimatedPlaceholder));




        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Test.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxAnimatedPlaceholder));
```

Comment: You should read the WPF data binding documentation. There does not seem to be an element named `_this`, which is required by the ElementName property of a Binding. Either set `x:Name="_this"` on the UserControl, or change the Binding expression to `{Binding PlaceHolder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Clemens comment solved my issue by changing the binding instruction to " {Binding PlaceHolder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}} "
Thank you Clemens, I've been trying for days . I was following this video [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-opr7BFOT0&t=835s) I asked the author but he deleted my questions after my first post.